# How can I iterate through a variable in dataframe while the same time aggregating by another variable and assign labels as a new variable?

Tags: python, function, loops, aggregate

```
timestamp   IFPID   Outcome Share Price Trade Qty   Date
0   10/05/2022 08:04    SP3K4K5 dn  36  100 2022-10-05
1   10/05/2022 08:04    SP3K4K5 up  64  100 2022-10-05
2   10/05/2022 08:04    SP3K4K5 up  65  100 2022-10-05
3   10/05/2022 08:04    SP3K4K5 dn  35  100 2022-10-05
4   11/05/2022 00:54    SP3K4K5 up  57  64  2022-11-05
5   11/05/2022 00:54    SP3K4K5 dn  43  64  2022-11-05
```

I want to new variable Expected(a binary class with buy or sell) which will be computed based on the aggregation of the the Date and Outcome variables by the share price variable and assign buy when the mean of the of up outcome for a particular date is higher than the mean of the dn outcome.

Comment: can you please give an example using some real values from the table you provided?

Comment: Date
Outcome
Share Price
(mean)
Expected
2022-10-05
up
64.5
Buy


dn
35.5
Buy

Comment: Let me understand this a little better. So let's say for a particular date (let's say 2022-10-05) the mean of Outcome = up is 64.5 ((64+65)/2) and the mean of Outcome = down is 35.5. so the first four rows are expected to get labels like buy, sell, buy, sell?

Comment: The label in that case would be sell all through for the four observations because when the means of the up and down is compared the mean of down is higher

Comment: hmmm but the mean of dn is not higher!!?? dn is 35.5 up is 64.5

Comment: I only displayed the head of the dataset, there are cases where the mean of dn are higher than up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250626/discussion-between-arinze-and-shirin-yavari).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'outcome': ['dn', 'up', 'up', 'dn', 'up', 'dn'], 'share price': [36,64,65,35,57,43],'date':['10/5/22', '10/5/22', '10/5/22', '10/5/22', '11/5/22','11/5/22']})
print(df)
```

[image]

```
piv = df.pivot_table(index="date", columns="outcome", values="share price", aggfunc='mean', fill_value=0)
piv['label'] = np.select([piv['dn']<piv['up'],piv['dn']>piv['up']], ['sell','buy'])
piv
```

[image]

Comment: This is very much closer to what is expected but the label is the problem, for any day there can only be one label either it's buy all through or sell all through like in this case the label for both dates should be sell for the six observations since in all the cases the mean of the up was higher than the mean of down

Comment: so if the mean of up is higher than dn it's sell, otherwise buy?

Comment: please accept my response if it is what you want! you may have to switch the labels to adjust the desired output.